# Access VBA: Close Form Without Saving

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've come across an interesting problem here. I'm trying to close a form manually (by clicking the "X" button on the form tab) without the form saving. I simply want the form to close and nothing attempted to be saved in any of the tables.

I think it'd be something to do with the `Form.OnClose` property, but can't find out anything past that.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how bound forms in Access work. On closing, they always save an edited record.

Your best choice is to put a "Close without saving" button on the form, with

```
Private Sub btClose_Click()

    ' Undo current changes
    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Undo
    ' Note that acSaveNo applies to design changes, e.g. if you have set a filter or sort order
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo

End Sub
```

Unless you want to do stupid things like making all bound record saves impossible:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Undo

End Sub
```

Then you can close the form with "X" without saving, but you can't save anything with Access functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This totally worked for me. As for closing the form on "X" on the top right corner, I disabled it (so users cannot click on "X" to close the form):
Right click on form > Form properties: Property sheet appears on the right hand side.
Choose Format and set option Close Button to No